# writing to value in list skips items

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a python list with dicts from where I pull the price variable such as:

```
def pricing():
    for index,i in enumerate(data):
        price = i['functions']['price']
        data['price'] = price
        return data
```

I further do some calculations based on other values in the list, for I. But the Price variable only gets multiplied by a number **larger than 0**.

When I run 10.000 results, it returns approx 3000 results, where price == "". After rerunning it for the empty prices, the amount of price == "" diminishes, but doesn't go to 0 which it should.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong here why it doesn't get all prices, is the data to big, how should I go with it?

Comment: can you add some example data?. is dificult to follow otherwise

Comment: @LucasM.Uriarte it's a file with 300K lines, {'id':'XXXXXX','functions':{'price':1200}}

Comment: This code does not do anything. It goes through all items in `data`, reads something from, and then discards it. It does not return anything. The code does not relate to the description at all. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: BTW there is no need to `enumerate` here.

Comment: @zvone enumerate is used to pop values from the data input that do not meet the requirements, as it is a list with dicts, I use enumerate to index the dicts as it is not sortable.

Regarding price only itering, I set price as
data['price'] = price in the bottom of the for loop

Comment: None of that happens in the shown code.

Comment: Adjusted @zvone

Comment: As others have pointed out, you still do not have a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) - from your description _sounds_ like you are modifying the list while iterating over it, which will invalidate the indices and cause you to miss elements.

Answer (score 0):

```
data = [1, 2, 4, "",""]
for i, item in enumerate(data):
    if item == "":
        data[i] = 0
```

> I have not a simple data but i hope it is solution for your problem.

- You can change the where price == "" to int 0.
- This way you get rid of unnecessary data. Your list could be clearer.

Comment: I don't set price =="" to 0, I set price as data['price'] = price, that is an example based for checking the empty values, and there is no int, the field is empty